# What are the names of the seconds for Anand vs Gelfand WCC 2012?

Tags: world-championship

Who are the seconds for Anand and Gelfand in the WCC 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anand's seconds are:

```
Peter Heine Nielsen
Rustam Kasimdzhanov
Surya Shekhar Ganguly
Radosław Wojtaszek
```

Gelfand's seconds are:

```
Alexander Huzman
Michael Roiz
Evgeny Tomashevsky
Pavel Eljanov
Maxim Rodshtein
Levon Aronian (to a lesser extent)
```

Gelfand discussed his preparation and seconds in a [post-match interview](http://www.chessvibes.com/reports/boris-gelfand-i-was-by-no-means-inferior-in-this-match-interview-part-1-of-2) with [chessvibes.com](http://www.chessvibes.com/).

Comment: Any references?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2012#Seconds

Comment: What is your source for Aronian acting as one of Gelfand's seconds? I have not heard that.

Comment: @EdDean - Weird.  Good Catch.  I had no idea how Levon Aronian got in there. I can only think that wikipedia made a mistake initially or I subconsciously put Aronian in there :). It's fixed now.

Comment: @xaisoft - Yeah, I was guessing wikipedia had it at some point and then it got removed. I was wondering if you maybe had some inside information :)

Comment: @Andrew - Ah nice.  My mind is playing tricks on me.

Comment: @xaisoft that is the only "official" reference I've found that mentions Aronian, it will be interesting to hear what is said now that the match is over.

Comment: I changed the answer slightly due to Gelfand's interview with chessvibes, now linked above